# jQuery ajax override global onSuccess handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible possible to have jQuery `.ajax` call to execute a global *onSuccess* handler (let's call it *onSuccessGlobal* for now) **before** executing the local *onSuccess* handler?

Basically, the flow should be:

1. Perform `.ajax` call (or `.get`, `.post`, etc)
2. Assuming previous call was successfull, a global `onSuccessGlobal` handler is invoked, passing the resulting *data* from the request. This **data is transformed** within this method.
3. After previous handler returns the transformed data, it's received by the local `onSuccess` handler which uses the data to add content to the page, etc.

I'm aware of the existence of the [Ajax events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/), but so AFAIK, it doesn't look that `ajaxSuccess` event will:
a) be called before the local `success` event
b) have the modified data sent to the local event

In order to achieve something similar, I think I could use the global `ajaxSend` event to abort the current ajax request, create a wrapped one with the handlers I need, and then send the new wrapped request instead. But I hope someone can provide some insight as this sounds rather complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just call your global `onSuccess` within the `onSuccess` callback of `$.ajax`? Then wait for the data to be returned from your global one before doing anything else in `onSuccess`:
`$.ajax...onSuccess: function (data) { var transformed = globalOnSuccess(data); // do something with transformed }`

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem ?

Comment: @CarlMarkham: Because is a codebase-wide change, so having local `onSuccess` calling the global one is out of the equation (>600 hundred calls I believe).

Comment: @adeneo, yes it's a very rough solution I wanted to try. The root problem is persistent XSS injection happening through ajax requests, and I thought filtering any output received through ajax calls, would be an all-in-one solution that was worth trying at least... I know it's definitely not the way to protect vs XSS attacks but we're in a bit of a rush.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to overwrite the `$.ajax` function. Not pretty but it gets the job done:

```
// Add `enableAjaxFiltering` & `disableAjaxFiltering` methods to jQuery object
(function( $ ) {
  // keep a reference to the old ajax function
  var _old = $.ajax;

  // use this namespace
  $.ajaxFiltering = {};

  // this will enable filtering in any $.ajax() call
  $.ajaxFiltering.enable = function(filter) {
    $.ajax = function(settings) {
      if (settings.success) {
        var callback = settings.success;
        settings.success = function(data) {
          newData = filter(data);
          return callback(newData);
        }
      }
      return _old.apply(this, [settings]);
    }
  };

  // this will disable filtering in any $.ajax call
  $.ajaxFiltering.disable = function() {
    $.ajax = function(settings) {
      return _old.apply(this, [settings]);
    }
  };

}( jQuery ));
```

Then you would just use enable before  `$.ajaxFiltering.enable(someFilteringFunction)` where `someFilteringFunction` will be responsible for returning the XSS free JSON.

Oh JS, how dirty you get sometimes :)

Comment: BTW, I'm using jquery 1.11 so it uses the old $.ajax signature.